# Uncaught Syntax error javascript onkeyup in asp text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Withing the asp code I'm adding onkeyup attribute like this to the text box.

```
txtName.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "ShowLength");
```

And within my .js file I have the ShowLength function

```
function ShowLength()
{
   alert('key up');
}
```

when I press the Ctrl it show the javascript error. But not for the other keys.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[accesskey=]
    at Function.t.error (JQuery.js:4)
    at t.tokenize (JQuery.js:15)
    at Function.t [as find] (JQuery.js:4)
    at t.fn.init.find (JQuery.js:16)
    at t.fn.init.pe.fn.init (JQuery.js:16)
    at t.fn.init (JQuery.js:60)
    at pe (JQuery.js:3)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.keyPressed (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.markitup.pack.js:9), <anonymous>:1:8652)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (JQuery.js:16)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.g.handle (JQuery.js:16)
```

Comment: try `txtName.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "ShowLength();");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your ASP.NET code where you are assigning the attribute `onkeyup` to the `txtName` as

```
txtName.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "ShowLength();");
//with brackets () and semicolon
```

This will properly add a function `ShowLength()` on `txtName` control for `onkeyup`. Your code resulted in a `undefined` value for `onkeyup`.

For adding parameter to the function

```
txtName.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "ShowLength("+ param +");");
```

Comment: I had few changes to my function(added a parameter). Still error comes even with this solution.
txtName.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", string.Format("ShowLength('{0}');",para);